# Android View taking all the space bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have put the last GridView under the View, but the View takes all his space, so the GridView is not displayed . I want the view to fill the empty space in the screen but not to take the space of other components.
I tried to set the view height to match_parent but it's not working.
Ho can i solve this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:text="@string/default_colors"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridViewMain"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/texto2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp">
</GridView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:text="@string/other_colors"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridViewMain"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/chooseColors"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/color_picker"
    android:layout_below="@+id/texto"
    android:onClick="onClickOtherColors"/>

<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_buttons"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/chooseColors" >
  </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to fix View height and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Gridview's height is only known after the measurement pass is completed during runtime. For your purposes I suggest you to use linearlayout with weights. Something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#303030"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="adfdefault_colors"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#303030"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="adfdefault_colors"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```